# How does one create, caption, label and refer to a subfigure?

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, subfloats

So its a fairly simple question to a problem people normally experience. I have a rough idea of what to do, but I am looking for the correct way of doing things. So in the solution I will include what would be the bare minimum requirements I think would get this problem solved. I am looking for feedback and corrections though.

So please tell me, how does one go about creating subfigures within a figure. After that, caption it. Then label it for reference and then refer to it in the text?

Comment: I am including this here since i can't answer my own question yet:

    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{subfig}

In the body the subfigure file is called a, b and so on.

    \begin{figure}
    \subfloat[caption for subfigure a \label{a}]{\includegraphics[options like trim, crop]{a.jpg}}
    \subfloat[caption for subfigure b \label{b}]{\includegraphics[options again]{b.jpg}}
    \caption{caption for the full figure}
    \label{whole}
    \end{figure}

While I am in the body I refer to the full figure as `\ref{whole}` and then refer to the subfigures like `\ref{a}` and `\ref{b}`

Comment: You could edit your question for including code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) package for this. For a brief guide on how to use it, including captioning, labeling and referencing, have a look at the excellent [LaTeX WikiBook section](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Subfloats) covering it.

Comment: I forgot about this source. I've come right!

Answer (score 7):

The [subcaption](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package provides three ways to build your subfigures:

1) Using the `\subcaption` command inside, for example, `minipage`s; the syntax:

```
\subcaption[<list entry>]{<document caption>}
```

2) Using the `subfigure` environment.

3) Using the `\subcaptionbox` command. The syntax:

```
\subcaptionbox[<list entry>]{<document caption>}[<width>][<inner-pos>]{<contents>}
```

where `<width>` is the width of the resulting `\parbox`; the default value is the width of the contents. `<inner-pos>` specifies how the contents will be justified inside the resulting `\parbox`; it can be either `c` (for `\centering`), `l` (for `\raggedright`), `r` (for `\raggedleft`), or `s` (for no
special justification). The default is `c`.

Here's a little example, illustrating the three approaches, and the use of `\ref` and `\subref` to cross-reference the (sub)figures:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \rule{3cm}{1cm}% to simulate a figure
  \subcaption{Test subfigure one}
  \label{fig:sub11}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \rule{3cm}{1cm}% to simulate a figure
  \subcaption{Test subfigure one}
  \label{fig:sub12}
\end{minipage}
\caption{A figure with two subfigures}
\label{fig:testfig1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \rule{3cm}{1cm}% to simulate a figure
  \subcaption{Test subfigure one}
  \label{fig:sub21}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \rule{3cm}{1cm}% to simulate a figure
  \subcaption{Test subfigure one}
  \label{fig:sub22}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Another figure with two subfigures}
\label{fig:testfig2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subcaptionbox{Test subfigure one\label{fig:sub31}}[4cm]{\rule{3cm}{1cm}}%
  \subcaptionbox{Test subfigure two\label{fig:sub32}}[4cm]{\rule{3cm}{1cm}}
  \caption{Another figure with two subfigures}
  \label{fig:testfig3}
\end{figure}

As we can see in Figure~\ref{fig:sub22}...

Subfigure~\subref{fig:sub32} of Figure~\ref{fig:testfig3} shows...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks Gonzalo! Very thorough! Just missed how to do it with `subfig` package!

Comment: @Eshwar, strategically, `subcaption` and `floatrow` with its `subfloatrow` env. are superior to subfig (not maintained AFAIK) and to `subfigure` which is obsolete.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`floatrow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package like in [Vertically align subfloats at the top while having subcaptions vertically aligned below the subfloats](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29536/vertically-align-subfloats-at-the-top-while-having-subcaptions-vertically-aligne/29590#29590).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\ffigbox
{%
  \begin{subfloatrow}
    \ffigbox
    {%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw circle (1.25cm) {};
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
    {%
      \subcaption{Small circle}%
      \label{fig:c:sc}%
    }
    \ffigbox
    {%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw circle (2cm) {};
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
    {%
      \subcaption{Big circle}%
      \label{fig:c:bc}%
    }
  \end{subfloatrow}
}
{%
  \caption{Circles}%
  \label{fig:c}%
}
\end{figure}

See the circles in Figure~\ref{fig:c}. There is a small circle, \ref{fig:c:sc}, and a big circle, \ref{fig:c:bc}.

\end{document}
```

[image: The output of the example]