# Label all figures in tabular

Tags: tables, floats, labels

I've found this code [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211546/5-figures-arranged-in-3-rows-x-2-columns) and I need to know if someone knows how can I label all the figures to be able to make a reference to them in the text and to appear for example: "In figure 1A..."

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure} [H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b} &
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-c} \\
\textbf{(a)}  & \textbf{(b)} & \textbf{(c)}  \\[6pt]
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b} \\
\textbf{(d)}  & \textbf{(e)}  \\[6pt]
\end{tabular}
\caption{ \textbf{(a)} Some text
\textbf{(b)} Some text
\textbf{(c)} Some text
\textbf{(d)} Some text
\textbf{(e)} Some text}
\label{fig:Name}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Take a look at the subcaption package.

Comment: Thanks @leandriis and @campa but that's not what I'm looking for, I do not intend to modify that figure, but simply that in the text I can put  `\ref{fig:1a}` for example and it will recognise it as valid

Comment: and @campa this is not a subfigure, is a tabular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have control over the pictures and their labels, then you should definitely use the approach described in the answers to the question [How does one create, caption, label and refer to a subfigure?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32536/110998).

If the five images and their captions are a single image that you do not want to dissect, you can define a command `\extralabel{labelname}{subnumber}` in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\extralabel[2]{{\edef\@currentlabel{\@currentlabel#2}\label{#1}}}
\makeatother
```

and later can reference `labelname` with `\ref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\extralabel[2]{{\edef\@currentlabel{\@currentlabel#2}\label{#1}}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b} &
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-c} \\
\textbf{(a)}  & \textbf{(b)} & \textbf{(c)}  \\[6pt]
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b} \\
\textbf{(d)}  & \textbf{(e)}  \\[6pt]
\end{tabular}
\caption{ \textbf{(a)} Some text
\textbf{(b)} Some text
\textbf{(c)} Some text
\textbf{(d)} Some text
\textbf{(e)} Some text}
\label{fig:Name}
\extralabel{fig:Name:a}{(a)}
\extralabel{fig:Name:b}{(b)}
\extralabel{fig:Name:c}{(c)}
\extralabel{fig:Name:d}{(d)}
\extralabel{fig:Name:e}{(e)}
\end{figure}

See subfigures \ref{fig:Name:a}, \ref{fig:Name:b}, \ref{fig:Name:c}, \ref{fig:Name:d}, \ref{fig:Name:e}.


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly! :D

Answer (score 3):

If you have control over the five pictures and their captions, then you can let the `subcaption` package handle the subcaptions and sublabes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering  
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
  \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:Name:a}}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}} &
  \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:Name:b}}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}} &
  \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:Name:c}}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-c}}
\end{tabular}
\medskip

\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:Name:d}}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}} &
  \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:Name:e}}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-c}}
\end{tabular}
\medskip

\caption{ \textbf{(a)} Some text \ref{fig:Name:b}
\textbf{(b)} Some text
\textbf{(c)} Some text
\textbf{(d)} Some text
\textbf{(e)} Some text}
\label{fig:Name}
\end{figure}

See subfigures \ref{fig:Name:a}, \ref{fig:Name:b}, \ref{fig:Name:c}, \ref{fig:Name:d}, \ref{fig:Name:e}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer