# How to add two pictures in a single column? How to add four pictures in a single row?

Tags: graphics, two-column

I am doing a paper for an ACM conference and I want to add some graphics pictures. I want to add two pictures in a single column and four pictures in single row. How is it possible?

Comment: [subcaption](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf) and [floatrow](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/floatrow/floatrow.pdf) might be your friends. see [How to build and combine sophisticated layouts in figures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43010/15717)

Comment: Also, if your paper is twocolumn, remember to use `figure*` (with asterisk) environment to allow it to spawn the two columns (for the four in a row figure).

Comment: See also [Make two figures aligned at top](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101858/make-two-figures-aligned-at-top) and [How to vertically center two images next to each other?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7219/how-to-vertically-center-two-images-next-to-each-other) (but these are for one-column mode!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be nothing tricky about this. You could just string them next to one another in a `figure` environment. Scaling to fit within the column is done using a fraction of `\columnwidth`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{graphicx,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
  \centering%
    \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-a}\hfill%
    \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-b}%
    \caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-3]

\begin{figure}
  \centering%
    \includegraphics[width=.23\linewidth]{example-image-a}\hfill%
    \includegraphics[width=.23\linewidth]{example-image-b}\hfill%
    \includegraphics[width=.23\linewidth]{example-image-c}\hfill%
    \includegraphics[width=.23\linewidth]{example-image-a}\hfill%
    \caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[4-5]
\end{document}
```

If you wish to have the (sub)figures numbered, then a little more work is required. If you wish to have the images span multiple columns, then you could use [`multicol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) which, again, would require a little more work.

Answer (score 0):

For 2 pictures in a column: Have the images aligned in the same place and scale them. 
For several pictures in a row: Just scale the pictures small enough so they fit on one line

When importing do something like

```
    \includegraphics[scale = 0.5]{my_pic.eps}
```