# ACM template: add pictures in a single row on both columns

Tags: positioning, templates, acm, overpic

I wanted to ask how to position pictures in ACM template in a row covering both columns. For example, when I add pic1, pic2, pic3 and pic4, they go below each other. I need two of them to stay in the same row (1 per column) and other two right below them. I found a tread: [How to add two pictures in a single column? How to add four pictures in a single row?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102021/how-to-add-two-pictures-in-a-single-column-how-to-add-four-pictures-in-a-single)
but it doesn't help me.

Can anyone help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a two-column float.

[image: alexAcmDblFloat]

```
\documentclass[prodmode,acmtap]{acmlarge}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\acmVolume{2}
\acmNumber{3}
\acmArticle{1}
\articleSeq{1}
\acmYear{2010}
\acmMonth{5}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
    \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image}\hfill
    \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}\par
    \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}\hfill
    \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image-c}
\end{figure*}
\section{Introduction}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```