# Subfloat vertical alignment in latex

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, subfloats

If I have to pictures of different height and the same width, how can I dock them to the top that both pictures are vertically aligned. This is my code so far:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
       \subfloat[Part 1]{%
          \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{pic1.png}%
          \label{fig:left}%
       }
       \subfloat[Part 2]{%
          \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{pic2.png}%
          \label{fig:middle}%
       }
       \caption{Stuff will be here.}
       \label{fig:default}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Sub-float package assumes that it is important to vertically align the captions, and therefore typically relies on a baseline alignment of the sub-float content.

Using [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox)'s `valign=t` option, the image's (the sub-float content) regular `b`aseline alignment could be altered to now be at the `t`op. However, you may also want to insert an appropriately-sized companion for the shorter image... do that by using `\vphantom{<larger image>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering

  \subfloat[Part 1]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-a}%
  } \quad
  \subfloat[Part 2]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-10x16}%
  }

  \subfloat[Part 1]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-a}%
    \vphantom{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-10x16}}%
  } \quad
  \subfloat[Part 2]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-10x16}%
  }

  \caption{Stuff will be here.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For those who are looking for center alignment, make all valign=c

Comment: I spent an afternoon and a morning struggling with that. That's exactly what I needed, I couldn't thank you enough.

Comment: did anyone get? `Package keyval Error: valign undefined. ...xtwidth,valign=t]{figures/circuitth.png}}`

Comment: @ItsmeJulian: You need `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` in your preamble. Did you add that?

Comment: See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/593361/how-to-horizontally-and-vertically-align-a-matrix-of-subfloats) for the case with tikz figures instead of graphics, where this solution cannot be used.

Comment: The second part is such an amazing trick

Comment: For anyone struggling with alignment: do not forget to add the `valign` inside the phantom too. I forgot this, with the result that there was lots of blank space above if you top- or center-align.