# How to achieve top-alignment of images in subfigure?

Tags: vertical-alignment, subfloats

There are some threads about subfigures and alignment, but I could not find a solution for my problem. I want to have two figures side by side, both with their own capture (a and b) and below one capture for both. Using

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Caption describing fig a}
        \label{fig:figure_a}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=7cm]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Caption describing fig b}
        \label{fig:figure_b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Caption for both images}
    \label{fig:Filter_L_LCL}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

gives me this:
[image]

and using my graphics I get this, so it is quite the similar situation:

[image]

Exactly what I want, expect the image alignment. I'd like to have them top-aligned and captions bottom-aligned (the image size must not be changed since image and document font size match). How can this be done? Any solution without manually shifting?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You should edit your question to make your code a complete compilable minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050)) beginning at `\documentclass` and ending at `\end{document}` providing all we need to compile it and reproduce your issue/error, but nothing more. For images you should use `example-image` in `\includegraphics`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152818/top-aligned-subfigure-with-bottom-aligned-caption looks like a duplicate of your question, does any of the answers there help?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Subfloat vertical alignment in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/296624/5764)

Comment: This seems to come up a lot:  see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331118/how-do-i-align-both-baseline-and-caption-in-a-horizontal-tikzpicture-subcaption

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can obtain it with the `floatrow` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx, floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\floatsetup{valign=t, heightadjust=all}
\ffigbox{%
\begin{subfloatrow}
\ffigbox{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-a}}{\caption{Caption describing fig a \label{fig:figure_a}}}
\ffigbox{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{example-image-b}}{\caption{Caption describing fig b} \label{fig:figure_b}}
    \end{subfloatrow}}
    {\caption{Caption for both images}
    \label{fig:Filter_L_LCL}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why isn't the _total caption_ shown? (_"Caption for both images"_)

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten it! 'Tis fixed now.

Comment: _Bernard_, sorry but if i run your MWE, the _total caption_ is not generated!. I don't know what is happening or if the problem is mine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is a nice and short solution that works well!

Comment: @skpblack: Did you run the last version of the code? Initially, as I focused on the top-alignment, I had forgotten to check the total caption was there.

Comment: @jesterhead, if this answer satisfies your expectations, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 3):

Move the shorter image into position using `\raisebox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}

\newsavebox{\tempfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \savebox{\tempfig}{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{example-image-b}}% Store larger image in box
    \raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\tempfig-\height}{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-a}}
    \caption{Caption describing fig a}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=7cm]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Caption describing fig b}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Caption for both images}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The height of the raise is given by the difference between the height of the larger image (`\ht\tempfig`, where `\tempfig` is the box containing the larger image) and the smaller image (`\height` - the natural height of the element contained within `\raisebox`'s second argument).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using similar code: (pay attention to "\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}" and " valign=t"

```
\documentclass{eage2024}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!tbp]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, valign=t]{8a.png}
    \caption{cc.}
    \label{fig:h1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, valign=t]{8b.png}
    \caption{cc2.}
    \label{fig:h2}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, valign=t]{8c.png}
    \caption{cc3.}
    \label{fig:h3}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, valign=t]{8d.png}
    \caption{Triple layer-thickness 1.}
    \label{fig:h4}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{cc4.}
\label{fig:h5}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It would help to explain what your suggested changes are doing.