# Entering subcaptions for figures without using subcaption environment

Tags: captions, diagrams, subcaption

I'd like to realize this picture in LaTeX to show radiation of the dipole. I've already ask this question [Radiation diagram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467983/radiation-diagram).  But, I need to have the caption for each diagram WITHOUT using `\subcaption`! (because in my code I need to use `\subfigure` for something else and we can't use at the same time `\subcaption` and `\subfigure`,...)

[image]

My code is the following (taken from [marmot's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467985/73)) to the linked question:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{floatrow}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=1.16}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \floatsetup{valign=c, heightadjust=all}
    \ffigbox{%
    \begin{subfloatrow}
    \ffigbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view/h=45,axis lines = none,unit vector ratio=1 1 1]
            \addplot3[domain=0:360,domain y=0:360,samples=31,
            point meta=sqrt(x^2+y^2),
            colormap/blackwhite,surf,%mesh,point meta=1, %<-if you want a mesh
        z buffer=sort]
           ({(sin(x+90)*sin(x+90))*cos(y)}, 
            {(sin(x+90)*sin(x+90))*sin(y)}, 
            {(sin(x+90)*sin(x+90))*sin(x)});
    \end{axis}
    \path(current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north
    east);
    \end{tikzpicture}}{\caption{Diagramme de rayonnement du dipôle.\label{fig:Diagramme de rayonnement du dipôle}}}
    \ffigbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{polaraxis}[axis lines = none]
        \addplot[domain=0:360,samples=73,smooth] (x+90,{sin(x)*sin(x)});
    \end{polaraxis}
    \draw[-stealth] ([yshift=2cm]current axis.south) -- ([yshift=-2cm]current axis.north);
    \end{tikzpicture}}{\caption{Coupe verticale du diagramme de rayonnement.\label{fig:Coupe verticale du diagramme de rayonnement}}}
    \end{subfloatrow}}
    {\caption{Rayonnement du dipôle demi-onde.}\label{fig:Rayonnement du dipôle demi-onde}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess that people are hesitating to help for two reasons. 1. There is no code. How on earth would anybody know which fragment they are to provide that does not clash with your code? 2. `subfigure` is often said to be deprecated. There may not be enough motivation to replace something that is not deprecated by something that is. (And I guess you might benefit from linking [this code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467985/121799) such that those who are willing to help have a starting point.)

Comment: I'm just looking for an other way to realize the picture in latex. A different code than the one in the other topic if it's possible. I really need it...

Comment: @Aurélien Thatnks for adding an example. It looks like that is taken from a previous answer to another of your questions. Usually, in such a case it's best to state explicitly that where it's from: helps give credit and makes sure any issues (or queries) can be tracked back to a source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

mwe for above image is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{3D presentation of dipole radiation}
\label{fig:dipol-1}
    &
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=3cm]{example-image-duck}
\caption{3D presentation of dipole radiation}
\label{fig:dipol-2}
\end{tabularx}
\end{figure}

or

\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=c]{example-image-duck}
    &
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=3cm,valign=c]{example-image-duck}\\
%
\caption{3D presentation of dipole radiation}
\label{fig:dipol-1}
    &
\caption{3D presentation of dipole radiation}
\label{fig:dipol-2}
\end{tabularx}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

in case that you like to include code of images,  than with them replace `\includegraphics ...` and for their vertical align use option `baseline ...` for the `tikzpicture`. Since you not provide mwe, i can't show anything further.

**addendum:**

Following the edit to the question (which uses code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467985), if i understood you correctly, you looking for the following:

[image]

it is generated with the following *mwe*:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage{floatrow}  % not used in this mwe
                        % however it is troublemaker. do you really need it?
\usepackage{caption}    % not used in this mwe
\usepackage{subcaption} % not used in this mwe
\usepackage{tabularx}   % <--- new

 \usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
% left image
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view/h=45,axis lines = none,unit vector ratio=1 1 1]
        \addplot3[domain=0:360,domain y=0:360,samples=31,
        point meta=sqrt(x^2+y^2),
        colormap/blackwhite,surf,%mesh,point meta=1, %<-if you want a mesh
    z buffer=sort]
       ({(sin(x+90)*sin(x+90))*cos(y)},
        {(sin(x+90)*sin(x+90))*sin(y)},
        {(sin(x+90)*sin(x+90))*sin(x)});
\end{axis}
\path(current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Diagramme de rayonnement du dipole.}
\label{fig:Diagramme de rayonnement du dipole}
    &
% right image
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[axis lines = none]
\addplot[domain=0:360,samples=73,smooth] (x+90,{sin(x)*sin(x)});
\end{polaraxis}
\draw[-stealth] ([yshift=1.6cm]current axis.south) -- ([yshift=-1.6cm]current axis.north); % corected yshift
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Coupe verticale du diagramme de rayonnement.}
\label{fig:Coupe verticale du diagramme de rayonnement}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

to obtain above image i  comment (removed) package `floatrow`. Do you really need it? Apparently it somehow redefine appearance of captions in `figure` environments (allow only one caption) and consequently in above *mwe* cause errors.

Almost all, for what i see that it is used in your document, can be achieved with `subcaption` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage{floatrow}  % not used in this mwe
                        % however it is troublemaker. do you really need it?
\usepackage{subcaption} % not used in this mwe
\usepackage{tabularx}   % <--- new

 \usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
% left image
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view/h=45,axis lines = none,unit vector ratio=1 1 1]
        \addplot3[domain=0:360,domain y=0:360,samples=31,
        point meta=sqrt(x^2+y^2),
        colormap/blackwhite,surf,%mesh,point meta=1, %<-if you want a mesh
    z buffer=sort]
       ({(sin(x+90)*sin(x+90))*cos(y)},
        {(sin(x+90)*sin(x+90))*sin(y)},
        {(sin(x+90)*sin(x+90))*sin(x)});
\end{axis}
\path(current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Diagramme de rayonnement du dipole.}
\label{fig:Diagramme de rayonnement du dipole}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfil
% right image
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[axis lines = none]
\addplot[domain=0:360,samples=73,smooth] (x+90,{sin(x)*sin(x)});
\end{polaraxis}
\draw[-stealth] ([yshift=1.6cm]current axis.south) -- ([yshift=-1.6cm]current axis.north);  % corected yshift
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Coupe verticale du diagramme de rayonnement.}
\label{fig:Coupe verticale du diagramme de rayonnement}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{Rayonnement du dipole demi-onde.}
    \label{fig:Rayonnement du dipole demi-onde}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

in both case i slightly corrected second image (see both mwe)

Comment: I'm just looking for an other way to realize the picture in latex. A different code than the one in the other topic if it's possible. I really need it...

Comment: sorry @Aurélien, i don't understand what is your problem.  you already got a number suggestions how to draw dipole radiation diagrams, also how to include include images (this is independent from image contents) in document. beside this you not showing what you try so far and where you stuck in this. you should be more clear, what is your problem.

Comment: to continue ...  @Aurélien, please provide mwe (minimal working example), a complete small document beginning with `\documentclass ...` and preamble (with to your problem relevant packages) `\begin{document}` some dummy text and how you so far inserted your images in document, and ending it with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have to realise a project about dipole in latex with others people. The problem is that I can't use the code given in the other topic because he needs \subcaption to work. Indeed, in my project somebody else is using \subfigure. \subcaption and \subfigure can't be use at the same time so my project doesn't compile. Does this make sense..?

Comment: @Aurélien, but i show you how to manage this. and without seeing mwe is any discussion worth less. if you will provide it, me or some else will  repair it that it will working.

Comment: I add my code at the top

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87948/discussion-between-aurelien-and-zarko).