# Strange behaviour of 3D pgfplots example

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I am trying to reuse the example shown in [this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467983/radiation-diagram) for another polar plot. that is r=a*sin(n.theta). The output is kind of what I expect as I will post here

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines = none,
xmin=-1, xmax=1,
ymin=-1, ymax=1,
zmin=0, zmax=1,
] %<- done it in a similar way to 2D plots not quite sure it worsk liek that in 3D
\addplot3[domain=54:126,domain y=0:180,samples=31,
colormap/blackwhite,surf,%mesh,point meta=1, %<-if you want a mesh
z buffer=sort]
({(sin(5*x)*cos(x))*cos(y)}, 
{(sin(5*x)*cos(x))*sin(y)}, 
{(sin(5*x))*sin(x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but the negative part circled in red in the attached picture I am not able to get rid of it.
Many thanks in advance,[image]

Comment: Well, `{(sin(5*x))*sin(x)}` does become negative in the `domain=54:126`, so what do you expect? Or, in other words, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes I agree and would expect to have a negative part but why it appear while I use `zmin=0`? this is not yet clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is how to remove the part with negative `z`: this is one way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines = none,
xmin=-1, xmax=1,
ymin=-1, ymax=1,
zmin=0, zmax=1,
] %<- done it in a similar way to 2D plots not quite sure it worsk liek that in 3D
\addplot3[domain=54:126,domain y=0:180,samples=31,
colormap/blackwhite,surf,%mesh,point meta=1, %<-if you want a mesh
z buffer=sort]
({ifthenelse((sin(5*x))*sin(x)>0,(sin(5*x)*cos(x))*cos(y),0)}, 
{ifthenelse((sin(5*x))*sin(x)>0,(sin(5*x)*cos(x))*sin(y),0)}, 
{max((sin(5*x))*sin(x),0)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Other ways include using filters, or just using other domains.

Comment: That is a much better as we render a clean version of what we want. However, why it cannot exclude the part below using the `zmin`, `zmax` macros? Is it a programming problem or a rendering problem?
Many thanks,

Comment: @Mazen It is a 3D “problem “. You cannot simply trim the graph by clipping it. Points with a smaller z coordinate may be higher up in the projected graph if they have other X and y values.