# How to adjust the height of subfigures of different sizes?

Tags: graphics, subfloats

I have the following piece of code

```
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{A_big_figure}
\label{fig:my_fig_1}}
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{A_small_figure} 
\label{fig:my_fig_2} } 
\label{my_fig_all}
\end{figure*}
```

with the second graphic being much smaller than the first one, but of the same width (i.e. just scaling it won't be useful for me). Currently, Latex aligns me the bottom of both figures i.e. there is a blank above the second figure. However, I would like the contrary, that is having the top of both figures aligned with a blank space below the small one. I tried byadding some negative white space before the second figure but this does not work.

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/296625/134144 could be helpful.

Comment: There is also `\raisebox{-\height}{...}` to align tops.

Comment: Your question's title is about how to "adjust the height", while the body is about alignment. You might want to improve the title (and maybe also the tags).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the `floatrow`  package and its `subfloatrow` environment:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{floatrow, subcaption, graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!ht]
\floatsetup{style=plain, floatrowsep=qquad, heightadjust=object, valign=t, captionskip=3ex}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]
{\begin{subfloatrow}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Traccia Table}\label{flt1}}
{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{traccia-table}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Fur breakfast}\label{flt2}}
{\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{dejeuner1}}
\end{subfloatrow}}{\caption{Meret Oppenheim}\label{Meret}}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With inserting images in table and for caption use of `\subcaption{<caption text>}`. With `valign=t defined in` \adjustbox` is moved images baseline to their top:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf,
            skip=0.5ex,belowskip=1ex
            ]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{p{0.45\linewidth} p{0.45\linewidth}}
    \includegraphics[valign=t]{example-image}
    &   \includegraphics[valign=t]{example-image-duck}  \\
\subcaption{}
\label{fig:my_fig_1}
    &   \subcaption{}
        \label{fig:my_fig_1}
\end{tabular}

\caption{My images}
\label{my_fig_all}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]